# PowerShell New-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'OtherAttributes' is specified more than once

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365

I'm trying to automate AD user creation with PowerShell.

This is the code:

## Create AD User

```
New-ADUser -Name $DisplayName `
-SamAccountName $SamAccountName `
-GivenName $FirstName `
-Surname $LastName `
-DisplayName $DisplayName `
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
-Enabled $true `
-PasswordNeverExpires $False `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
-UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
-EmailAddress $PrimaryEmailAddress `
-OtherAttributes @{'proxyAddresses' = $proxyAddressesEmailMandatory} `
-OtherAttributes @{'ipPhone' = $UserExtension} `
```

Attribute "proxyAddress" is necessary so we can have Azure AD Sync between on-premise AD and Azure AD.

But now, we are trying to connect FreePBX with on-premise AD. In order to achieve that, we need to have "ipPhone" attribute.

Before I added last line, script was working fine.

I can see where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. Help with an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
New-ADUser -Name $DisplayName `
-SamAccountName $SamAccountName `
-GivenName $FirstName `
-Surname $LastName `
-DisplayName $DisplayName `
-AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `
-Enabled $true `
-PasswordNeverExpires $False `
-ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
-UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName `
-EmailAddress $PrimaryEmailAddress `
-OtherAttributes @{
    'proxyAddresses' = $proxyAddressesEmailMandatory
    'ipPhone' = $UserExtension
}
```